# Sql Query - stuck with simple left join

Tags: sql, mysql

I've been stuck with this simple Sql query for last 3 hours and my mind is drawing blank.

I have a User table that captures name user_id etc
Then I have a friends table that captures who is friend of whom and their status

**User**

user_id
name

**Friend**

friend_id
user_id
user_friend_id
status (accepeted,pending etc)

What I want to do is - when a logged in user searches for a name say "John" - display a list of all johns on the website and next to each John - do a lookup with a friends table to see if the record exists - ie if the logged in User is a friend of any of the Johns

- if it exists show the current status
- if it does not exist then show "Add Friend"

So should I first run a query on User table like select user_id from User where name Like 'John%' and then use those Id's and run them against Friends table.

I am not able to get it.
Thanks

Comment: hey mdm - this is what I'm doing so far
- running a seperate query to get user_ud names like John from User table
- then checking each of these user_ids with the Friends table to see if anyone of them are friends of the logged in User

This works but I was thinking if there is a single query that I can write to accomplish that - something that return for each user_id of John name - what the friendship status is with the logged in user and null if they are not friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with all users that match your criterium (I'm not sure about the exact MySQL syntax):

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM User u
WHERE u.name LIKE '%John%'
```

This gives you all target users. Next you want an outer join on the `Friend` table where you restrict the results to the currently logged in user:

```
SELECT u.user_id, f.status
FROM user u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Friend f ON f.friend_id = u.user_id
WHERE f.user_id = <currentUserId> AND u.name LIKE '%John%'
```

What you get is a result set that has the user ids of all users named John and a status flag that is either null or an actual status. If it is null, you have a potential new friend, if not, you have an existing friend.

Comment: Thanks - the explanation you provided made it very clear where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Something like this might get you started.**

- [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html)

*SQL Statement*

```
SELECT u.name, COALESCE(f.Status, 'Add Friend')
FROM   User u 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Friend f ON f.User_ID = u.User_ID
WHERE  u.name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following query must solve your problem

`select a.user_name,case when a.user_name like 'John%' then b.status else 'Add Friend' end case from users_det a,friend b where a.user_id = b.user_id`